# Attached entity does not get update with new values when SaveChanges is called

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there anything wrong with this code? My entity is not getting updated.

```
public ActionResult UpdateNota(string notas)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        RegistroEntities registroEntities = new RegistroEntities();
        Nota nota = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Nota>(notas);
        registroEntities.AttachTo("Notas",nota);
        registroEntities.ApplyCurrentValues("Notas", nota);
        registroEntities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
        return Json(new {success=true});
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [Entity Framework documentation entitled Working with Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738470.aspx), in particular the section on [Attaching and Detaching Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx).

In this case, you're calling `AttachTo`, which places the entity in the `Unchanged` state.

Then you call `ApplyCurrentValues`, which copies all the values in the entity over its own values; any values *that have a different value* are marked as modified. (Note that since each value is just copied over itself, *none* of them have a different value, so the entity remains in the `Unchanged` state).

Finally, you call `SaveChanges`. Since the entity is in an `Unchanged` state, there is nothing to do.

The MSDN documentation links at the beginning of this answer contain information about the correct way to do this (note that *adding* the entity uses a different solution than *updating* the entity).